# AngularJS Nested Promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, ngcordova

I'm trying to return this `.register()` method:

```
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $cordovaPushV5.initialize($constants.PUSH_OPTIONS).then(function () {
        $cordovaPushV5.onError();
        $cordovaPushV5.onNotification();

        return $cordovaPushV5.register();
    }).then(function (push_token) {
        deferred.resolve(push_token);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
```

But it is never resolving with push_token... This seems to be correct according to other questions i've seen, However I can't get it to work properly.. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!.

Comment: You mean that `then( fun (push_token))` triggers before `register` is done? Also share `initialize`.

Comment: Guys sorry i think it's my bad, seems $cordova push notifications will trigger only if running on a mobile device and won't work in the simulator. I will double check this and get back to you. Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: Don't use `$q.defer()` to compose promises. You already have a promise  from `$cordovaPushV5.initialize`, wrapping it with `defer` will just lead to mistakes (in this case you've omitted to propagate the error callback to the deferred).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Cordova, but Promise seems fine.
But it can be simplified :

```
    return $cordovaPushV5.initialize($constants.PUSH_OPTIONS)
        .then(function () {
           $cordovaPushV5.onError();
           $cordovaPushV5.onNotification();
           return $cordovaPushV5.register();
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: Check update : If you add the error function, you might uderstand what's going wring